# Test if any file was downloaded with SFTP command

Tags: shell, ssh, openssh, sftp

How to get the return code of SFTP command?

I do this to download all files from a directory. But if the directory is empty the command returns `1`

How to fetch the actual code for `File not found`?

```bsh
echo 'get * /var/download' | sftp -b - user@host
```

Or a solution would be to ignore/suppress the error `File not found` and return `0` (not suppress all errors, only this one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSH `sftp` returns 0 on success and 1 on error.

No further distinction is provided.

---

To test, if any file exists in a directory before trying to download them, you can use:

```sh
echo "ls /remote/path/*" | sftp -b - user@example.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Files exist, can download now"

    echo 'get /remote/path/* /local/path/' | sftp -b - user@example.com
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Files successfully downloaded"
    else
        echo "Files exist, but failed to download"
    fi
else
    echo "Files do not exist"
fi
```

---

For a similar question, see [How to check if file exists in remote SFTP server from local Linux script?](https://superuser.com/q/850158/213663)